# compile a c program with gcc in cmd ( .c, .cpp and .h)

Tags: c, gcc, cmd

I have 3 files:

```
 mainOperations.cpp
 operations.c
 operations.h
```

(does some functions, is not importat what is in, for what I am looking)

I was trying to run from cmd with gcc like this:
"gcc -o C:...\ mainOperations.cpp operations.c operations.h" but it say "No such file or directory" for all of them. 
So, my question is what to do to run with gcc from cmd? (Windows 7)Thx!

Comment: Did you install gcc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you have written would in the worst case overwrite you `mainOperations.cpp`.

There are several things you might have missed.

1. You have a `cpp` file, which is probably C++ and not C, for which you would not need `gcc`, but `g++` (`g++` is also able to handle C Code! So if you have mixed code, use `g++`).
2. The parameter `-o` specifies the output file, which you have pointed to your `cpp` file, thus, if the compiler gets to work, he overwrites that file with binary code and gives you very fuzzy errors.
3. You dont need to pass `.h` or `.hpp` files to the compiler, but you need to tell the compiler where to find them

The easiest way to achieve what you want would be:

```
g++ -o "c:\mybinary.exe" "c:\path\to\files\*.cpp" "c:\path\to\files\*.c" -I"c:\path\to\files\"
```

What it does: It generetes the file c:\mybinary.exe out of all `cpp` and `c` files in `c:\path\to\files` whilst searching headerfiles also (not only) in `c:\path\to\files`, where your `.h` files lie.

All of that could have been told by the manpage or the documentation, so next time, show some research effort. There are plenty of resources telling you how to use a compiler!